# Deleting cell value if "Quit" button selected

Tags: excel, vba

I have 1 userform for login called "LoginForm" and 3 additional userforms "AMForm", "FMForm" and "HRMForm" that open up if the user's details are correct. There are 3 spreadsheets "AMChoices", "FMChoices" and "HRMChoices" where the contents from the 3 additional userforms are recorded into the relevant spreadsheet i.e. FMForm into FMChoices. 
To specify the user, their UserID appears in the relevant spreadsheet if their credentials are accepted. For example, if is userform "AMForm" their UserID is entered into the next available cell in column B in "AMChoices" (starting at B3). As there are multiple users logging in, it enters to the next empty row.

The code I have works perfectly. However, on each userform "AMForm", "FMForm" and "HRMForm" there is a "quit" button. So I want it to delete the recently entered UserID.

How can I code this? I have entered the code I use to enter the UserID into the spreadsheet from the LoginForm. Please let me know :)

```
Private Sub btnAMLogout_Click()
    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to quit? Press Yes to proceed and No to cancel.", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        Unload Me
    End If
End Sub

If aCell.Offset(, 4) = "SBUB10" Then
    AMForm.Show
    With Worksheets("AMChoices")
    LastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.CountLarge).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    If LastRow < 3 Then LastRow = 3
    .Cells(LastRow, "b") = WorksheetFunction.Proper(ID)
End With
```

Comment: You are in the right spot, just add some code, make an effort please. Maybe some soft heart here will write it for you but it's highly unfair, besides being entirely unprofessional, isn't it? I do apologize if I misunderstood your writing.

Comment: Hi Gene, sorry if this came across this way - my VBA skills are quite limited and with this query in particular I'm not sure even where to start. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippet of code you've shown writes the ID into the worksheet. To remove it, you need to find it and blank out the cell it is in. This action can be performed either before the`Unload Me` call or after it. The code you have needs some modifications:

```
Private Sub btnAMLogout_Click()
    If MsgBox("Are you sure ...", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        Unload Me
' Let's say the new code goes here. The last ID (whichever it is) will be removed.
        With Worksheets("AMChoices")
            LastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.CountLarge).End(xlUp).Row ' no need for:  + 1
            If LastRow < 3 Then Exit Sub ' no need for:  LastRow = 3    
            .Cells(LastRow, "b") = "" ' no need for:  WorksheetFunction.Proper(ID)
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Now, since you've mentioned multiple users, it might be a bit more complicated because you need to find the cell with the ID in question (it might not be the last one!) and then delete it. The "deleting" could be just emptying the cell (as above) or deleting the whole row of that cell, or something else--I do not know your situation well enough to say which it is.

Anyway, to look for the last occurrence of that ID in column "B:B" you need to test the cells in the column to have that ID, starting from the last cell and going up, one cell at a time, something like

```
For i = LastRow to 3 Step -1 
    If .Cells(i, "B") = WorksheetFunction.Proper(ID) Then
        .Rows(i).Delete
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

I sure hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Gene, this is excellent. I really do appreciate your help and the time you took to write this. Thank you very much have a good day :)